why can we declare $ as an identifier for instance (int $=24;) but not _ as (int _ =24)?
Declaring identifiers in java has some rules, identifier name starts with _,$ or alphabets where we can simply simply declare characters and currency symbol as an identifier but not underscore symbol.
why?
I tried declaring int $ =24; which didn't invoked any error but when i tried declaring underscore an error was invoked by the compiler whereas the rules of declaring an identifier clearly states that an identifier can begin with underscore or currency symbol.
int $=24;(error free)
int _ =24;(error)

Because the JLS says so. If you want to know why the JLS says so, I recommend asking either James Gosling or the OpenJDK developers.

Also _ is reserved for use as an unnamed variable.

@Turing85 I don't think your comment is entirely correct. The _ identifier used to be valid before Java 9. James Gosling left Sun Microsystems before the decision was made to make this a reserved identifier. I see too many people saying "you need to ask the JDK developers" when in fact the reasons can often be found in published release notes.

Because the Java architects decided to no longer allow using a single undersore as identifier. See JEP-302 for the rationale.

BTW with Java 22 (and later) you can declare a variable (even more than one in same scope) named with a single underscore, no compilation error - but you cannot reference it by name

(only valid in certain declarations like local variables for example)

@user85421 Interesting, but can you think of any situations in which declaring a local variable as "_" is not entirely pointless?

@k314159 yes I can, but I don't need to, it does not matter; the writers of JEP 456 did think of an example, and that matters. ( But I can only think of one reason for your question :-/ )

@user85421 thanks for the JEP link. I was wondering why would a simple declaration like var _ = sideEffect(); be of any use when you can just call sideEffect(); without assigning the return value to anything. But all the other usages shown in JEP 456 (such as in for loops, try-with-resources, etc.) are useful.

You can't use the underscore _ as an identifier from Java 9 onwards because it is a reserved keyword. It is intended for use as an unnamed lambda parameter. The reasoning behind this is explained in JEP 302.
The use of _ as an identifier was valid in Java 7 and earlier. In Java 8, its use resulted in a compiler warning. From Java 9 onwards, it is an error. However, you can still use the underscore as part of a longer identifier, such as _abc or even __ (though not recommended).

@any_reader please check JEP 456 which allows the usage of _ as identifier in certain declarations (Java 22 and later)
